# Writing a dictionary to txt file, any way to format it?

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I wrote a little function to take dictionaries in Python and convert them to a txt file.

```
def dict_to_txt(dict, name):
    dict = {'dict': dict}

    with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(dict))
```

My output looks like the following:

```
{"dict": {"A": "America", "B": NaN, "C": "?", "D": NaN}}
```

Is there any way that I can  output a formatted dictionary like this:

```
{"dict": {"A": "America", 
          "B": NaN, 
          "C": "?", 
          "D": NaN 
 }
}
```

or some variation of this. To give you some context, I have a list containing dictionaries and am applying this function via iterating through the list..

Comment: Looks like custom formatting task.

Comment: Oops! I got it - super easy.. editing below

Comment: If you're using `json.dumps`, it has an `indent` parameter which can create an indented output. It's not exactly the format you show but it's more readable than the all-on-one-line approach. (And, IMO, more readable than the stacked notation you show in your example.)

Answer (score 3):

```py
def dict_to_txt(dict, name):
    dict = {'dict': dict}

    with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(dict, indent=2))
```

Comment: It should be `file.write(json.dumps(dict, indent=2))`